# I want to use memset to remove some characters from string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, memset

I used `memset()` to remove `text.txt` from `path` string, but the below code is not working.

Please let me know what is the problem.

```
char *path = "tt/tt/tt/text.txt";
char *direc = "";
int minus = 0;
int i;

for (i = strlen(path) - 1; i > 0; i--)
{ 
    if (path[i] == '/')
        break;
    else
        minus++;
}
memset(path + i, '\0', strlen(path) - minus);

printf("%s", path);

return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, `path` points to a *string literal*, which is usually present in read-only memory. You may not change the content of that.

Instead, try using an array like

```
char path[ ] = "tt/tt/tt/text.txt";
```

Comment: thangk you. Now, it't wokring! :)

Comment: @Olaf I strongly recommend you to read chapter §6.4.5, `C11` standard, paragraph 7 before making such comment. Fell free to ask if anything is not clear. :)

Comment: My bad! Forgot about that. Objection withdrawn. Thanks for the correction.